# 'forward replace' with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where every row looks something like this:

```
series = pd.Series({0: 1.0,
 1: 1.0,
 10: nan,
 11: nan,
 2: 1.0,
 3: 1.0,
 4: nan,
 5: nan,
 6: nan,
 7: nan,
 8: nan,
 9: nan,
 'B': 3.0,
 'D': 1.0})
```

For every value in D I want series[series.D] to be 2 and, all  numerical values that are higher than series.D, also to be 2. It's kinda like a 'forward replace'. 
So what I want is:

```
target = pd.Series({0: 1.0,
 1: 2.0,
 10: nan,
 11: nan,
 2: 2.0,
 3: 2.0,
 4: nan,
 5: nan,
 6: nan,
 7: nan,
 8: nan,
 9: nan,
 'B': 3.0,
 'D': 1.0})
```

So far I've got:

```
def forward_replace(series):
    if pd.notnull(series['D']):
        cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
        target_cols = [x for x in cols if x > series.D]
        series.loc[target_cols].replace({1:2}, inplace=True)
return series
```

It seems like it's not possible to use label based indexing with numerical column labels?

Comment: I'm confused. Why are we mixing int and str in index?

Comment: That's a byproduct of a previous operation (pivot)

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you are asking for, but perhaps are you looking for something like this: `s[(~s.isnull()) & (s <= s['D'])] = 2.0`? (where `s = series`)

Comment: Thank's for your time! Your solution replaces all non-empty-cells that are smaller than s.D, but what I want is replace all non-empty-cells from all columns which label is equal to or greater than s.D. Hope this makes it clearer